# Autosys job not to trigger twice during some period

Tags: autosys, jil

My job A is dependent on the parent job B and A is triggered when B succeed.
The problem is that B may finish several times during the day by mistake (bug in upstream).
How could I make A depend on B and trigger only if it was not already triggered the same day?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't found any other solution but introducing new 'defensive job' in the middle with:

```
command: (( "X$(date +%F)" != "X$(cat defensive_trigger_date)" )) && ( echo $(date +%F) > defensive_trigger_date; echo $(date +%F) )
```

High level logic:

- If current system date is not equal to last job trigger date (from the file) flush current system date to the file and exit with zero exit code (succeed the job)
- Else exit with non-zero exit code (fail the job)